# Run XCode Integration from command line

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration

I have set up os x server and bot which do build/test process. I need run this bot from command line.
Is it possible to run integration (CI on os x server) from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite late response, nevertheless hope it would help.

As you might know Xcode Server exposes [WEB API](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeServerAPIReference/index.html). 
So in order to launch integration just issue this command replacing YOUR_BOT_NAME part with actual bot name.

```
curl -sk -X POST -d '{ shouldClean: false }' https://localhost:20343/api/bots/`curl -sk https://localhost:20343/api/bots | jq '.results[] | select(.name == "YOUR_BOT_NAME") | ._id' | tr -d '"'`/integrations
```

---

Note this command utilises [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line JSON processor which is available via Homebrew:

```
brew install jq
```

Answer (score 0):

Build can be done with xcodebuild. For tests, I don't know.

Comment: Actually, I need to run bot integration to start build/test process on the build server.